# how to display image in oracle apex (image saved as LONG RAW datatype in a table)

Tags: image, long-integer, display, apex

I have images stored in LONG RAW datatype in oracle 11g, how to display the image in oracle apex page?

Comment: Please update your question with what you are currently trying and what is specifically going wrong :-)

Comment: I have A/c holder's image stored in oracle database table as LONG RAW datatype. How to display these image on oracle Apex page?